# "Global" global variable is not accessible from GUI window

Tags: python, variables, tkinter

I'm currently trying to create a window with Tkinter which displays a text with the variable `text1`. My plan is that when I change the variable, which I run with **another file**, it also changes in the window.

! ATTENTION: When I use the `import CreateWindow` command another window will open, so it doesn't fit in my plan

`CreateWindow.py`

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
lab = Label(root)
lab.pack()

text1 = "Connecting..."

def update():
    global text1    
    lab['text'] = text1
    root.after(1000, update) # run itself again after 1000 ms

# run first time
update()

root.mainloop()
```

`Connected.py`

```
text1 = "Connected!"
```

When I run the `Connected.py` the text in the window won't change.

Comment: Global variables are usually a really bad idea, so try and find another way. Why can't you have a function here that returns the expected text instead of trying to manipulate shared state? A single entry point gives you way more control, and it's easy to `import`.

Comment: global variables are *global to the module*. the variable in `connected.py` has nothing to do with `createwindow.py`. Note, these two scripts don't import one or the other, so it isn't clear why you expected this to *work at all*.

Comment: @tadman what do you mean "global up front"? Where else would the OP use the `global` statement?

Comment: And it is important to understand, `global text1` is **not required** and *shouldn't be used* in your `def update():` function.

Comment: "which I run with another file, it also changes in the window." wait, are you saying *you are running two separate processes*? Then it will never work!

Comment: If you want data to be shared between different scripts, save it in a file.

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to your question. Instead, accept the answer once you can (click the hollow checkmark under the vote count so it turns green. Clicking it again will unaccept).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to build a window where I can see the status of something... Here are my final solutions (thanks to @[Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) for the idea)

**CreateWindow.py**

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
lab = Label(root)
lab.pack()

with open('cache.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('Connecting...')

def update():
    with open('cache.txt', 'r') as file:
        data = file.read().rstrip()
  
    lab['text'] = data
    root.after(1000, update) # run itself again after 1000 ms

# run first time
update()

root.mainloop()
```

**Connected.py**

```
with open('cache.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('Connected!')
```